# Virtual machine BLE support for Linux guest

Tags: virtualbox, bluetooth, vmware, bluez

I am using latest Ubuntu image as a guest on a Windows host.
I want to use hcitool for ble the output is as follows:

```
sudo hcitool lescan

Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

Although I'm able to do a simple

```
sudo hcitool scan
```

I have used different virtual machines software(virtualbox, vmware) but no success.
Is BLE not supported by Virtual Machines?

Comment: If you are using a USB Bluetooth dongle then it may be possible to get it to work in the VM if you implement USB pass through. This does not work with all Bluetooth dongles, though. I’ve only ever seen it work with TP-Link devices for some reason. If the Bluetooth device is built into your host, then it cannot be passed to the VM and you will need to live with the limitations of the VM’s hardware API layer 

Comment: I have a spare TP-Link dongle. I could disable the inbuilt bluetooth and use the dongle. How to do the usb passthrough any idea?